# vim-rest-console displays JSON in a single line

Tags: json, vim, indentation, neovim

I've found out about [vim-rest-console](https://github.com/diepm/vim-rest-console), but after installed and run a test, I noticed the JSON it outputs is only in one line, without any indentation. This is horrible and I'd like to know if there is a way to solve this. I am using NeoVim on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Apparently you can setup formatting for the responses. See `:h vrc_auto_format_response_patterns`. Might depend on `g:vrc_response_default_content_type` value. See `:h vrc_response_default_content_type`

Answer (score 2):

To fix the json indentation in Vim, put the following command to your `.vimrc`

```
nmap =j :%!python -m json.tool<CR>
```

and launch it via the `=j` command (or remap to different shortcut).

Comment: Sounds interesting but the one I provided doesn't need anything for it to be properly indented. It bugs me the idea I need to do it manually all the time. Thank you anyways.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, What if i get "Cannot make changes, 'modifiable' is off ?

Comment: EDIT: never mind -> :set modifiable

Comment: EDIT2: the solution with jq seems better for me :

nmap =j :set modifiable<CR>:%!jq<CR>